# Calling function in yet uninstanced object C#

Tags: c#, oop, object

I'm trying to create menu for my simple app. I want to use switch but I can't find a way to call functions in uninstanced class which is instanced on application startup.

```
class Window
{
    public void startLibrary(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        BookList MainLibrary = new BookList();
        this.mainMenu();
    }

    public void mainMenu()
    {
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch  (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":

                break;
```

How do I call MainLibrary's function in case 1. It's obviously not instanced here but I can't find a way pass reference to uninstanced object.

BookList code :

```
class BookList
{
    List<Book> books = new List<Book>();       
    public void addBook() // adding book
    {
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string author = Console.ReadLine();
        int relDate = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int uID = books.Count() + 1;
        books.Add(new Book(name, author, relDate, uID));
    }
    public void deleteBook() // deleting book
    {
        int readForDelete = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        books.RemoveAll(Book => Book.UniqueID == readForDelete);
    }
    public void borrowBook() // borrowing book
    {
        int readForBorrow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        foreach (Book Book in books)
        {
            if (Book.UniqueID == readForBorrow)
                Book.available = false;
        }
    }
    public void returnBook() // returning book
    {
        int readForReturn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        foreach (Book Book in books)
        {
            if (Book.UniqueID == readForReturn)
                Book.available = true;
        }
    }
    public void displayBooks() // displaying list of books
    {
        string isAvailable;
        foreach (Book Book in books)
        {
            if (Book.available == true)
                isAvailable = "available";
            else
                isAvailable = "unavailable";
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} ", Book.UniqueID, Book.BookName, Book.BookName, Book.ReleaseDate, isAvailable);
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but maybe you can pass the reference as a parameter to your `mainMenu` function.

Comment: You can't pass reference of something that doesn't exist. References are to object instances.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to pass your `BookList` instance to your `mainMenu()` method, or set a global variable.  I'd recommend the former.

```
public void mainMenu(BookList list) { ... }
```

Then call it like this from `startLibrary`:

```
this.mainMenu(MainLibrary);
```

---

As a side note, you really need to [brush up on your variable, class, and method naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspxhttp://).

Comment: Thank you, works prefect and the way I wanted to. My naming conventions are really sad, but I'm still trying to learn these.
I guess main problem with naming is PascalCasing in fields. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it with lambdas like this:

```
class Window
{
    public void startLibrary(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        BookList MainLibrary = new BookList();
        Action<BookList> action = this.mainMenu();
        if (action != null)
        {
            action(MainLibrary);
        }
    }

    public Action<BookList> mainMenu()
    {
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                return b => b.addBook();
        }
```

Or you could just pass a reference to your `MainLibrary` variable to the method:

```
class Window
{
    public void startLibrary(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        BookList MainLibrary = new BookList();
        this.mainMenu(MainLibrary);
    }

    public Action<BookList> mainMenu(BookList b)
    {
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                b.addBook();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Second solution works wonders! Thank you alot. Could you also explain the `return b => b.addBook()` and `Action` part? I've got no idea what's going on there. I'm really new to C# and coding itself. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The first example had an error. I just corrected that.

Comment: It is hard to explain lambdas and actions in a few sentences... Maybe this article helps: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/08/func-and-action-basics-in-c.html - or just google for "C# action lambda"

Comment: @Easy ah, so an instance of BookList actually **is** instantiated, and you needed to use it in another method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you've got in your startLibrary method is a local variable - which is accessible only within the block it's defined in. That said, the MainLibrary is not something you can reference from anywhere else.
To solve your problem you have several options.
You can make the MainLibrary a field/member of the Window class. Then all the instance methods of the Window class will have access to it - so as the MainMenu method:

```
class Window
{
    private BookList MainLibrary;

    public void startLibrary(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        this.MainLibrary = new BookList();
        this.mainMenu();
    }

    public void mainMenu()
    {
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch  (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                // do whatever you want with this.MainLibrary here
                break;
            /// ...
        }
    }
}
```

The other option would be to pass in the MainLIbrary instance you've created into the mainMenu method. Here you'll need to update the signature of the method as follows:

```
public void mainMenu(BookList list)
{
    // reference the list now as necessary
}
```